# Error calling webservice from JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, asmx

I have a strange problem when I'm trying to call a simple webservice method from Jquery.

Locally it works fine, but on my test-server it does not.

The jquery request looks like this (only showing the actual request and not the rest of the method):

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Service/Service.asmx/AddTab",
    data: "tab=" + element.innerHTML,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

When I run this locally from the test-server it works fine, which has me wondering if it could be some setting that I've missed in the IIS.

If I navigate to the .asmx file and click the AddTab method I get a list of SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2 XML, but not the HTTP POST request. If I navigate to it locally I get all three (SOAP 1.1, SOAP 1.2 and HTTP Post)

The service is set up as follows:

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "mynamespace")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService()]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    [ScriptMethod()]
    public void AddTab(string tab)
    {
        //Some code to add a tab which evidently works locally...
    }

   }
```

Anyone have a clue what I'm missing here?

Comment: .NET and IIS version?
Have you tried to set contentType on jQuery call?

Comment: 3.5, IIS 7 and yes, it works fine locally... and locally on the test-server as well... with or without contentType

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to finally solve this by adding the following to the web-config:

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Appearently the server was blocking the incoming requests from a remote host.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure web.config file is properly [configured](http://encosia.com/2010/03/08/asmx-scriptservice-mistakes-installation-and-configuration/).

Comment: The web.config looks exactly as specified in that post :/